# Facebook does not show the uploaded picture on profile page using android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to upload a picture from some URL on facebook but it is not posting any image on my wall. whereas when i tried the same code from my friend's account it works fine and upload picture over there. I am using standard facebook sdk and this code is a part of its example named as simple. Kindly help in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
           Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("method", "photos.upload");

            URL uploadFileUrl = null;
            try {
                uploadFileUrl = new URL(
                      "http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)uploadFileUrl.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                int length = conn.getContentLength();

                byte[] imgData =new byte[length];
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                is.read(imgData);
                params.putByteArray("picture", imgData);

            } catch  (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST",
                    new SampleUploadListener(), null);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

found the solution...just go to the privacy setting of the facebook account for pictures and albums and then click the approve button to allow the visibility of your album on your account.